# How to calibrate the UWP app for projection

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

this is my first question in this platform sorry if what im asking is a bit silly.

So I want to create an uwp app for my raspberry pi 3 and project it on somewhere. But the surface and the position of the projector is not that perfect.

I draw some geometrical figures on a CanvasControl. To test it I draw a square 1m x 1m. When i plug the hdmi and project the square that i draw wasnt even square. I measure the sizes. It was like 95cm x 102cm x 97 cm x 99 cm. If they would be same I would put some ratio to fix it. But they are all different. So what I understand is the projection that I made is not rectangle.

Is there any possibility fix this programmatically ? Im open for any ideas.

PS: The program is drawing some geometrical figues on a canvascontrol and show it.

Comment: "_Is there any possibility fix this programmatically_" Yes, of course. Measure the distortion introduced by the projector accurately and properly parameterize it as parameters of some kind of transformation function(s). Then based on the parameters of the distortion you measured, program a routine that does the exact inverse transformation(s) (which will counter/nullify the distortion introduced by the projector). Also, [Are “Point me in the right direction” questions acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/are-point-me-in-the-right-direction-questions-acceptable)

Comment: Hi Mustafa Uludağ, can you show a code sample to reproduce this issue?